# Проксирование в nginx с аргументами

Tags: nginx, проксирование

Имеется такой кусок конфига виртуального сервера в nginx, проксирующий определённый `location` на ноду сворм кластера. Там мобильное приложение ходит по своим делам.

```
 location ~ ^/service_location/(.*)$ {
                proxy_pass http://22.22.22.22:8082/$1$is_args$args;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_read_timeout 950s;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
                proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
                proxy_connect_timeout  70;
                proxy_send_timeout     70;
                send_timeout           70;
        }
```

Оно работает и всё было хорошо, но пришла задача сделать `upstream`, чтобы проксирование шло на несколько нод сворма.
Добавил сам апстрим

```
upstream upstream_name {
        ip_hash;
        server 22.22.22.22:8082 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
        server 33.33.33.33:8082 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
        server 44.44.44.44:8082 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
}
```

Поменял `proxy_pass` на

```
           proxy_pass http://upstream_name/$1$is_args$args;
```

И стал получать 400 ошибку, бэд реквест.
В интернете находил, что нужно убрать регулярку из location и `$1$is_args$args` из `proxy_pass`, но не помогло. Пробовал убирать по отдельности с тем же не успехом. Собственно, куда воевать и/или где почитать подробно, для дураков, как тут надо делать?

Comment: А что говорят логи апстрима?

Comment: В логе именно что только 400 ошибка, причём в access логе, error пуст. Пинаем GET запрос через curl -I

Comment: В логах сервера 22.22.22.22?

Comment: Да, с той стороны haproxy он давал 400 ответ. в целом вроде как проблема была в отсутствии параметра proxy_set_header Host $host в локейшене. Начнём тестирование посмотрим.